# Socksify php script

Tags: linux, php, socks-proxy, socks

I am trying to socksify php script network connections, however I am unable to do that, script ignores the socksifyer, just connects directly.

I tried using tsocks and torsocks.

```
tsocks php script.php.
```

Other programs work correctly with tsocks or torsocks. My tsocks.conf pointing to the correct socks proxy port. PHP just ignores socksifier. What is the problem?

Thanks